# Removing characters from a dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code for extracting the matching values from Category List and dataset.

```
matches= token.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).str.extractall("|".join(["({})".format(cat) for cat in Categories.HealthCare])))
match_list= [[m for m in match.values.ravel() if isinstance(m, str)] for match in matches]
match_df = pd.DataFrame({"Hc1":match_list})

def match_health(row):
    categories = []

    for bigram in row.bigram:
        joined = ' '.join(bigram)
        if joined in HealthCare:
            categories.append(joined)
    for trigram in row.trigram:
        joined = ' '.join(trigram)
        if joined in HealthCare:
            categories.append(joined)

    return categories

match_df['Hc2'] = df.apply(match_health, axis=1)
match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df[match_df.columns[[0,1]]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)
```

which yields the following result:

```
    Hc1                 Hc2                         HealthCare
0   []                  []                          [],[]
1   [Sauna, Jacuzzi]    [Health Club, Steam Room]   ['Sauna', 'Jacuzzi'],['Health Club', 'Steam Ro...
2   [Sauna, Jacuzzi]    [Health Club, Steam Room]   ['Sauna', 'Jacuzzi'],['Health Club', 'Steam Ro...
3   [Sauna, Jacuzzi]    [Health Club, Steam Room]   ['Sauna', 'Jacuzzi'],['Health Club', 'Steam Ro...
```

type(match_df)

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

But my Output should be without the '[]'- square brackets and single quotes around the strings like:

```
    Hc1                 Hc2                         HealthCare
0                                                   
1   Sauna, Jacuzzi   Health Club, Steam Room    Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
2   Sauna, Jacuzzi   Health Club, Steam Room    Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
3   Sauna, Jacuzzi   Health Club, Steam Room    Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
```

Need help.

Comment: wouldn't it be enough to just replace [ ] and ' with whitespace or just remove them?

Comment: Yes, replacing it with comma separator will also do the work

Comment: match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df['HealthCare'].map(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",''))  This works,but only to a dataframe column. Do you know how to apply it to the entire dataframe at a go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.str.replace`:

```
match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df['HealthCare']\
                          .astype(str).str.replace(r"[\[\]']", '')
```

Comment: I tried it but was unsuccessful. match_df = match_df.applymap(lambda x: x.translate(tab))
match_df

AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'translate'", 'occurred at index Hc1')

Comment: @RajithaNaik Why was it unsuccessful? If it worked for me, it could work for you.

Comment: I used maketrans , initially I got this error: cannot find name maketrans even after importing it from the string, and now 'list' object has no attribute 'translate''. Probably I am not clear on how to apply these functions in my code.

Comment: @RajithaNaik Try this now. It should be much faster than your solution.

Comment: No, Iam using Python 3. Jupyter notebook. I checked the Kernel now:kernel_name=python3

Comment: @RajithaNaik Well, it looks like your column is a column of lists of strings. :/ Please check my answer.

Comment: Yes it executes faster than my code. Thanks @COLDSPEED :) Could you please tell me how to apply this logic to the entire dataframe wherein I have more than 10 columns.

Comment: @RajithaNaik You have some options. You can either use a loop and call this same code for each column. You can also use `applymap` and replace but that might be slower, even without the loop.

Comment: Done ... Thanks a lot @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ :D

Answer (score 0):

```
match_df['HealthCare'] = match_df['HealthCare'].map(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",''))
```

This works in replacing all the square brackets and single quotes.

O/P:

```
      HealthCare
0                                                   
1   Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
2   Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
3   Sauna,Jacuzzi,Health Club,Steam Ro...
```